# Can a JobScheduler execute a foreground service?

Tags: android, android-service

Is it possible? I need to start my foreground service because I'm using it with the UI thread,

Example: Every 25minutes play a video in my app, which is it closed.

Comment: You want to play the video even if your app is not opened?

Comment: Yes, I need to start the app in foreground and play a service with a song

Comment: you must look at chat heads and use the same implementaion

Comment: what is "chat heads?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that this is not the best use case to use JobScheduler, but you can! First of all, you should create

```
public class ExerciseJobService extends JobService {
    private Context context;
    public ExerciseJobService(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YOUR_SERVICE.class);
        startForegroundService(intent);
        return true;
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

After that schedule Job

```
private FirebaseJobDispatcher jobDispatcher = FirebaseJobDispatcher(GooglePlayDriver(context)) 
Job myJob = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(ExerciseJobService::class.java)
                .setTag("SIMPLE_TAG")
                .setTrigger(Trigger.NOW)
                .build();
jobDispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```